# Onde devo colocar um método de cálculo? Na própria entidade ou na classe de negócios?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, hibernate, classes

Tenho uma dúvida arquitetural, eu acredito.

Preciso criar um método que receba um período de datas e uma entidade na qual executará uma pesquisa no período citado. Na verdade, para formular esta pergunta pouco importa quais são os parâmetros desse método. Importa saber que será feito um cálculo nessa entidade utilizando um algoritmo qualquer.

A dúvida é: onde colocar esse método? Na própria classe que representa a entidade ou na classe de negócios dessa entidade? Não sei se consegui me expressar corretamente.

Já ouvi falar em entidades anêmicas, que seriam entidades apenas com as representações das colunas e nada mais, sem regras de negócio. Como decidir isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No paradigma da orientação a objetos, um objeto na sua forma mais básica possui comportamentos.

Se um objeto não possui comportamentos, ele não passa de uma estrutura de dados (cuja declaração e instância em Java têm a mesma forma que a declaração e instância de objetos, ficando a diferença nesta linguagem, portanto, apenas conceitual).

Se suas entidades forem anêmicas (desprovidas de comportamentos), ficando todo o comportamento de negócio delegado a outros objetos (que pela provável ausência de estado de negócio em si serão na verdade apenas classes agrupando funções), você estará adotando de fato o **Anemic Domain Model**, [o que é, segundo a visão de alguns, algo muito distante da Orientação a Objetos](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html) (leia o artigo por favor para entender que, para Fowler, este é um **anti-pattern**).

Agora, se suas entidades publicarem todo o comportamento relativo a elas, sendo delegado a outros objetos apenas os comportamentos que não pertencem naturalmente a nenhuma entidade específica, então provavelmente você estará mais próximo do paradigma da Orientação a Objetos.

Se você deseja algo mais orientado a objetos, por assim dizer, então a decisão de se este método em questão pertence à própria entidade ou a uma outra classe depende sim de considerar qual é a função do método, ou seja: sobre o quê o método vai operar e quais resultados deve produzir. Não dá para decidir onde o método deve residir sem saber qual a sua função.

Answer (score 4):

Me parece que a resposta está na pergunta. Se você tem uma classe para a entidade e outra para as regras de negócio, não tem motivo para colocar este método na entidade. A classe de regras está lá justamente para ter todos os métodos que afetam aquela entidade. Neste caso você mantém a entidade como [classe anêmica](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html).

Porém nada no Hibernate exige isto e muitas pessoas consideram um exagero ter uma classe separada para regra de negócios. Se achar que é bom reduzir esta complexidade e ter só a entidade com as regras lá, a decisão fica fácil :)

O que é o melhor para o seu caso eu não posso dizer. Tente experimentar com as duas, mesmo que não chegue implementar ou colocar em produção.

Toda a programação está migrando para uma visão mais pragmática que adota classes anêmicas sempre que elas forem úteis. Algumas pessoas não vão desgrudar da visão anterior que era equivocada, mas cada vez mais vemos um direcionamento para algo menos ideológico nesse ponto.

Answer (score 0):

Não existe certo ou errado nesse caso, a arquitetura você mesmo define de acordo com a solução que precisa implementar. Se você extrai todas as regras de negócio da sua entidade e cria classes de serviço/negócios, então o mais interessante seria que esse cálculo também ficasse fora da sua entidade.

Mas nada o impede de incluir as regras de negócio nas entidades, existem situações em que uma entidade é desenvolvida de forma que ela possa "se resolver" sem depender de outras classes, dessa forma as regras ficariam dentro da própria entidade.